# neo4j how to query with variable nodes in between limiting the number of relations between subsequent nodes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, limit

Consider a query similar to this:

```
MATCH p=(b:label{ID:"M04"})-[r:Edge*2..2]-(d:label{ID:"S02"})
RETURN p LIMIT 10
```

Let me call the intermediate node `c`. The relations from `b` to the intermediate nodes and to the final node `d` are all of the same type `Edge` and have the property `EdgeID`. From one node to another there are different relations of type `Edge` each one with a different `EdgeID` property value. To the next node there are other relations of the same type and most of them having the same value of the property `EdgeID`.

For example the graph is similar to that:

```
(b)-[:Edge{EdgeID:1}]->(c)-[:Edge{EdgeID:1}]->(d)
(b)-[:Edge{EdgeID:2}]->(c)-[:Edge{EdgeID:2}]->(d)
(b)-[:Edge{EdgeID:3}]->(c)-[:Edge{EdgeID:3}]->(d)
....
```

The query returns many relations from `b` to `c` but a single relation from `c` to `d`

```
(b)-[:Edge{EdgeID:1}]->(c)-[:Edge{EdgeID:1}]->(d)
(b)-[:Edge{EdgeID:2}]->(c)-[:Edge{EdgeID:1}]->(d)
(b)-[:Edge{EdgeID:3}]->(c)-[:Edge{EdgeID:1}]->(d)
....
```

I want to return the paths with the relations having the same `EdgeID`. So for example with `LIMIT 1` I want to return only one among the above rows, for example

```
(b)-[:Edge{EdgeID:123123}]->(c)-[:Edge{EdgeID:123123}]->(d)
```

(not necessarily that ID)

With `LIMIT 2` I want to return two, for example:

```
(b)-[:Edge{EdgeID:123123}]->(c)-[:Edge{EdgeID:123123}]->(d)
(b)-[:Edge{EdgeID:872346}]->(c)-[:Edge{EdgeID:872346}]->(d)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Change `limit 10` to `limit 1`

Comment: Do you want to limit relationships between `b` and `c` only or total relationships returned?

Comment: My question is a little unclear: I will modify it to explain better.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it's clearer now

Comment: In the case of `LIMIT 2` ( more precise `LIMIT n`):  What if there are no relationships with the same `EdgeID` between b-c and c-d?

Comment: But there are relationships with different EdgeIDs on both sides

Comment: You can return relationships with same edge IDs but in that case, other relationships will not be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add the condition that the relationships in the path have the same property value:

```
MATCH p=(b:label{ID:"M04"})-[:Edge*2]-(d:label{ID:"S02"})
WHERE relationships(p)[0].EdgeID = relationships(p)[1].EdgeID
RETURN p LIMIT 10
```

And if you need this kind of restriction to be in place for arbitrary length paths, then you can do:

```
MATCH p=(b:label{ID:"M04"})-[:Edge*6]-(d:label{ID:"S02"})
WITH p, relationships(p)[0].EdgeID as edgeID
WHERE all(rel in tail(relationships(p)) WHERE rel.EdgeID = edgeID)
RETURN p LIMIT 10
```